# Does the Philips Hue Entertainment streaming API support remote access?

Tags: philips-hue

I haven't found any mention of remote access yet in the Entertainment streaming API docs.

The 'normal' (older) RESTful Hue API does have a remote API.

Does the Entertainment streaming API support remote connections too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: No, it doesn't. It only works over local networks.